# Unable to redirect in Spring MVC (using " :redirect/")

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, redirect

I am trying to post an image.
I have a form to upload(along with table containing all uploaded images)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
    <title>SpringImageApp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3 th:if="${#vars['flash.message']}" th:text="${#vars['flash-message']}" class="flash"></h3>
        <h3 th:text="${page.number + 1} + ' of ' + ${page.totalPages}" />
            <table>
                <thead>
                <th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Image</th>
                </thead>
                <body>
                <tr th:each="image : ${page.content}">
                    <td th:text="${image.id}"/>
                    <td th:text="${image.name}"/>
                    <td th:text="@{'/images/' + ${image.name} + ' /raw '}"/>
                </tr>
                </body>
            </table>
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/images">
                <p><input type="file" name="file"></p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>

            </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my Controller file

```
private static final String BASE_PATH="images"
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = BASE_PATH )
    @ResponseBody
    public String createFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){

        try{
            imageService.createImage(file);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flash.message","Successfully uploaded" + file.getOriginalFilename());

        }catch(IOException e){

            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flash.message","Failure  uploaded" + file.getOriginalFilename());


        }
        return "redirect:/";

    }
```

Everything works find until I upload image. It redirects to the URL `localhost:8080/images` displays the string `redirect:/` instead of root directory. I made another similar application(without thymeleaf template enfine) and it worked fine.
Is there a problem in my controller, service or my template engine?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `@ResponseBody` annotation from the method - this tells Spring that the response is to be serialised to JSON (more details here: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body#requestbody)

It looks as though it should work if you remove that annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove @RestController from your class and you need to use @Controller instead of @RestController.
And you need to remove @ResponseBody from your class methods. because @RestController and @ResponseBody will be using for response to be serialized to JSON.